# ORA-04098 trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle11g, triggers

I inserted this trigger in to my SQL Database and its Creating Successfully. But When i inserted a data evaluation No as 0 its giving an error:

> ORA-04098. This trigger is about when user inserting data into attendance table
>   if a data inserted as evaluation No = 0 the program should send that
>   info to 'evalAudit' Table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER zeroEval
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF evaluation_No 
ON Attendance
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.evaluation_No = 0)
BEGIN
IF :NEW.evaluation_No = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO auditEval 
SELECT stu.stud_Name, cou.course_Title, off.start_Date, off.instructor_ID, :NEW.evaluation_No
FROM Student stu, Offerings off, Course cou
WHERE stu.stud_ID = :NEW.stud_ID AND 
off.offering_ID = :NEW.offering_ID AND
cou.course_ID = off.course_ID;
END IF;
END;
/
```

This is the code of Table Creation

```
CREATE TABLE auditEval
( 
    stud_Name       VARCHAR2 (30) ,
    course_Title   VARCHAR2 (30),
    start_Date      DATE ,
    instructor_Name VARCHAR2 (20),
    evaluation_No   VARCHAR2 (10) 
 );
```

This is a code for data insertion to Attendance as evaluation No = 0.

This is the code of Attendance Table.

```
CREATE TABLE Attendance
  (
    evaluation_NO   VARCHAR2 (10) ,
    evaluation_Type VARCHAR2 (10) ,
    stud_ID       VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
    offering_ID   VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL
 );
```

Comment: Note: the `if` statement is redundant - the `when` clause of the trigger should take care of checking the condition.

Comment: Beside redundant dont know why `IF` use `:NEW` but `WHILE` use `NEW`.